# Query using a column which contains the value of another column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following table in SQL Server 2019

```
UserID(PK) - string - 30 characters
Useremail  - string - 100 characters
ManagerUserID - string 30 characters
```

Note: `ManagerUserID` is nothing but the `userid`

The data is

```
1, one@one.com, 2  ( 2 is the manager of user 1)
2, two@manager,com, 3 ( 3 is the manager of user 2)
3, three@boss.com, null (no manager as he is the boss)
```

How can we get user details and their manager details (they are just another user) by using one query?

These are my scripts

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[sampleusertable]
(
    [UserID] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [Useremail] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [ManagerUserID] [varchar](50) NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_sampleusertable] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([UserID] ASC)
                    WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, 
                          IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, 
                          ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

INSERT INTO [dbo].[sampleusertable] ([UserID], [Useremail], [ManagerUserID]) VALUES 
('1', 'one@one.com', '2'),
('2', 'two@manager.com', '3'),
('3', 'three@boss.com', NULL);
GO
```

Comment: First please show us your desired results so we understand what you are looking for. Second please show us what you have tried.

Comment: Could you create actual tables and sample data instead of quasi-JSON-English descriptions of your structure?

Comment: If you provide DDL+DML + desired results you'll get answers much faster.

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a subquery or a self `JOIN` to achieve this:

```
SELECT 
  a.UserID, 
  a.Useremail, 
  a.ManagerUserID, 
  (SELECT Useremail FROM sampleusertable WHERE UserID = a.ManagerUserID) AS ManagerEmail
FROM sampleusertable a
```

```
SELECT a.UserID,
  a.Useremail,
  a.ManagerUserID,
  b.Useremail AS ManagerEmail
FROM sampleusertable a
LEFT JOIN sampleusertable b ON a.ManagerUserID = b.UserID
```

**Result:**

```
| UserID | Useremail       | ManagerUserID | ManagerEmail     |
|--------|-----------------|---------------|------------------|
| 1      | one@one.com     | 2             | two@manager.com  |
| 2      | two@manager.com | 3             | three@boss.com   |
| 3      | three@boss.com  | null          | null             |
```

Optionally, you can add `COALESCE` to fill in `NULL` values with something else like this:

```
SELECT a.UserID,
  a.Useremail,
  COALESCE(a.ManagerUserID, a.UserID) AS ManagerUserID,
  COALESCE(b.Useremail, a.Useremail) AS ManagerEmail
FROM sampleusertable a
LEFT JOIN sampleusertable b ON a.ManagerUserID = b.UserID
```

**Result:**

```
| UserID | Useremail       | ManagerUserID | ManagerEmail     |
|--------|-----------------|---------------|------------------|
| 1      | one@one.com     | 2             | two@manager.com  |
| 2      | two@manager.com | 3             | three@boss.com   |
| 3      | three@boss.com  | 3             | three@boss.com   |
```

Fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/obL4EtTl).